# Google identity toolkit widget code

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

so,
I am trying to integrate google identity toolkit in my localhost website.
According to the guide i should find a personalised Widget code in my developers console.
This code as mentioned in googles documentation exists in "Google identity toolkit" option in the left bar when we are on the settings page of this API.
But i have no such option showing.

I know this might seem to be a silly question as i probably unable to find the code but can someone please help me on this one.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the developers console for your Gitkit project, make sure to follow this path: APIs > Enabled APIs > Identity Toolkit API > Settings. Once on the settings page, you should see the URL configuration fields up top, and the providers down below. Scroll down past the providers and you should see the sample widget code.

The example about halfway down the https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend page can be used as well if you replace the config options with your site's appropriate settings.

Comment: thanks for the answer ! Now i have another problem, My button for sign in changes to signed in(authentication part is successfull) , but there are no redirects after successfull login(my localhost site still remains on homepage)..i understand that i am missing the code(on the authorized redirect url page) for setting session from google redirect so can you suggest me links i can read to what exactly to do on the redirected page ? Basically how can i set session on my website after googles authentication is complete ?